# Retrieve id from API response with array

Tags: rest, guzzle

Hi I'm using REST API in my application to retrieving some data. I'm using GuzzleHttp library for that. My function  with request to API is:

```
public function createSurveyForCase()
    {

        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://localhost/survey/web/app_dev.php/api/']);
        $res = $this->client->request('POST', 'survey/', [
            'json' => [
                'base_survey_id' => 1,
                'client_trans_id' => '639252-2',
            ]
        ]);
        $survey = $res->getBody();

        return $survey;

    }
```

Below I show example of response from API:

```
{
    "hash": "8537f99bb4166da9f74f02ebb70907cf",
    "sending_date": "2017-08-23T08:32:37+02:00",
    "expiration_date": "2018-02-23T08:32:37+01:00",
    "created_at": "2017-08-23T08:32:37+02:00",
    "trans_id": "10-550\r\n",
    "id": 18,
    "status": {
        "name": "new",
        "id": 1
    },
    "base_survey": {
        "name": "Base Survey Test 1",
        "created_at": "2017-07-25T10:08:18+02:00",
        "creator_trans_id": "10-615",
        "date_start": "2017-07-25T00:00:00+02:00",
        "expiration_int": 6,
        "expiration_string": "months",
        "survey_prefix": "PSI",
        "welcome_message": "test1",
        "expiration_message": "test2",
        "id": 1,
        "template": {
            "path": "/template_ssi_1/",
            "name": "SSI",
            "id": 1
        }
    }
}
```

How could I retrieve id(with value 18) from this data? Im'trying to do in way:

```
$survey["id"];
$survey->id;
```

but it dosen't work

I bealivie that it works like associative PHP array.

I would be very greateful for help. 
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
public function createSurveyForCase()
{

    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://localhost/survey/web/app_dev.php/api/']);
    $res = $this->client->request('POST', 'survey/', [
        'json' => [
            'base_survey_id' => 1,
            'client_trans_id' => '639252-2',
        ]
    ]);
    $survey = $res->getBody().toArray();

    return $survey;

}
```

Then access it like **$survey['id']**

Comment: Thanks I've accessed that by:   $survey = json_decode($res->getBody()); 
                                                  $surveyId = $survey->id;